# Row-wise concatenation of a numpy-array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy-array consisting of strings and floats, and I want to concatenate each row of this array. For this I use map as shown here:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([["this", "is", "test", "nr", 1],
                ["this", "is", "test", "nr", 2],
                ["this", "is", "test", "nr", 3],
                ["this", "is", "test", "nr", 4]])

map(lambda x: x[0] + " " + x[1] + " " + x[2] + " " + x[3] + " " + str(x[4]), arr)
```

My question is, is this the fastest way to do it? Or does a native numpy-method exist that is faster than map?

Comment: the "num" is numpy stands for numerical. If your data isn't numerical, why are you using numpy?

Comment: @Julien My array is large (tens of thousands of rows), and I was under the impression that a numpy-array would be much faster for these kinds of operations (?)

Comment: again why a package designed for numerical computation would be efficient for string manipulation?

Comment: @Julien It is a mix of numerical and textual entries, not only textual

Comment: `numpy` doesn't have its own string methods.  `np.char` may have a `join` that works but it isn't faster than a list comprehension.

Comment: check your `arr`.  I think it is all strings

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[' '.join(row) for row in arr.tolist()]
```

`join` is faster than repeated '+'

It's faster to iterate on a list than on an array.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also recommend that I use a pandas dataframe instead?

Comment: pandas uses native python strings and object dtype columns.  I'm not familiar with its added string tools.

Comment: I mean in terms of efficiency - is it better to use pandas when the data is mixed str/numerical rather than numpy arrays?

Comment: The above code is incorrect. It should be `[' '. join(row) for row in arr.tolist()]`. But if you are going to convert to a List then this should be outside the comprehension for efficiency; Pandas uses numpy arrays internally and is intended for labelled columns/rows and offers no advantage,

Comment: wrote it on my phone without testing